# Need to make multiple changes to a string using data from a temp table

Tags: sql, csv, sql-server-2012

I have a CSV-style `varchar` that contains the IDs (foreign keys) of records in another table (that table is not important to this question). Note that this CSV always has leading and trailing COMMA chars.

```
Select ts_Associated_Requirements 
from usr_Change_Rqst:


,455,616,854,1093,1094,1095,1096,1097,1098,1123,1222,
```

I need to remove the IDs that are in the CSV and that are listed in a temp table created for me:

```
CREATE TABLE #TasksToReassign (ID INT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO #TasksToReassign  ....blahblah... ;

SELECT * FROM #TasksToReassign ;
```

Output:

```
 ID         
 -----------
         666
         854
        1093
        1094
        1095
        1097
        1098
```

This is a simplified example. I know that for a limited number if replacements I could nest `REPLACE()` statements, but that becomes unwieldy when the temp table contains 50 or more values to be removed and the CSV contains hundreds,

I don't have the database privileges to create functions, so please consider an answer using simple SELECT / UPDATE.

Original string:

```
    ,455,616,854,1093,1094,1095,1096,1097,1098,1123,1222,
```

What I want

```
    ,455,616,1096,1122,1223,
```

**NOTE**: This situation is for a commercial off-the-shelf software product.  I can't redesign their database or tables.

Using SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to parse and split the string on comma and return the individual ID. Check against the temp table and exclude those ID. Form the CSV back again

As you are on `SQL Server 2012`, you can't use `STRING_SPLIT`. You may use any CSV splitter. Here i am using Jeff Moden's [DelimitedSplit8K](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function)

Sample query

```
declare @ts_Associated_Requirements varchar(100),
        @new_list                   varchar(100)

select  @ts_Associated_Requirements  = ',455,616,854,1093,1094,1095,1096,1097,1098,1123,1222,'

CREATE TABLE #TasksToReassign ( ID int NOT NULL ) ;

insert into #TasksToReassign 
values (666), (854), (1093), (1094), (1095), (1097), (1098)

select  @new_list = isnull(@new_list + ',', '') + Item 
from    dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@ts_Associated_Requirements, ',') a
where   not exists
        (
            select  *
            from    #TasksToReassign x
            where   x.ID = a.Item   -- DelimitedSplit8K returns 2 column ItemNumber & Item
         )
order by ItemNumber

select  @new_list
```

Comment: Returns: Invalid object name 'dbo.DelimitedSplit8K'.  My DB privileges are rather limited if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: you need to create that function. See the link provided